# How to log unicode characters to the console in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, unicode, character-encoding, console, console.log

I have a Hungarian statement that I would like to log to the console like this:

```js
console.log('Probléma a működésben.');
```

But it prints the following:

```r
> ProblÃ©ma a mÅ±kÃ¶dÃ©sben.
```

The non ASCII characters are messed up, but I don't think the reason for this is that the console doesn't support Unicode characters, because if I paste the log straight into the console it produces the proper output.

I tested it in Opera, Firefox, Chrome. Happens in Win 8.1 and OSX too, so we can say this is general.

Are there other things that should persist for the proper Unicode console logging, like HTML charset or file encode?

Comment: What's your environment and which console are you talking about (chrome, firefox, terminal, ...)?

Comment: @Codespawner I tested it in Opera, Firefox, Chrome. Happens in Win 8.1 and OSX too, so we can say this is general.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found out that if you set the proper charset in a `<meta>` tag in the `<head>` it will work:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Comment: And this is why at least Firefox will display a warning on the console if you forget that tag. *The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. …*

Answer (score 13):

**First way**: you have to find your characters in [unicode table](https://unicode-table.com/en/)

> `console.log( '\u03A9' )`; // Ω

**Second way** - use [unidecode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/unidecode) npm package.

Comment: Sadly, neither of these worked for me in regards to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62727831/wrong-encoding-when-importing-json-with-polish-characters-in-javascript

Answer (score 5):

You can specify the encoding of your file by setting the charset attribute

```
<script src="script.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you must use this table UNICODE en internet, for example, with the character: 'Ã' do this:

```
string.replace(/\u00c3/g, 'é'); //And you can change all the symbols by what you want
```

This is with the first character you don't want and so so with the other characters

Ã == u00c3 and UNICODE