# PostgreSQL: Chinese characters are stored as a question mark

Tags: database, postgresql

I need to store words in my database that are in English and Chinese, among other languages.
I can see the database is created as UTF-8 by default and I have read that UTF-8 supports Chinese.

This is the instruction I'm using:

**INSERT INTO words (word1, word2) VALUES ('宿', 'whatever');**

So any idea why the Chinese characters are being stored as "?" ?

Comment: your data is corrupted on some step between its origin and the database table

Comment: I just added the line I'm using to store the values. Is there anything wrong with it? Is there anything other than the instruction that can be wrong?

Comment: the client inviroment you are working in may not support utf8. are you inserting from pgadmin? or from psql? try ```SHOW client_encoding```

Comment: I'm using VS Code's CLI.
That command gave me this as a result: WIN1252

Comment: try ```SET client_encoding = 'UTF-8';``` and insert some more data

Comment: It's funny because I can see it DOES change the encoding client to UTF8, however, the Chinese character continues to be stored as "?"

Comment: long time ago I had same problem when ```pgadmin``` was not able to display utf8 correctly, but the real stored data was Ok. try selecting via ```psql``` or ```pgadmin``` and read here about terminal and utf8 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57402483/how-do-i-configure-a-terminal-to-read-utf-8-characters

Comment: In this case, I don't think it's even being stored correctly, because when React calls the API, it displays the "?". I'll continue to look into it, but thank you for trying anyway, Igor.

Comment: ok, and what is result of ```SHOW server_encoding;``` ?

Comment: UTF-8, just like the client; I just tried using the regular Windows command line, but the result was the same.

Comment: to ensure the data is stored correctly or not try to use ```COPY ...``` command to dump the table into the UTF8 csv file and look at it contents

Comment: I just tried and it shows as "?" in the CSV as well :/